# My component.html file doesn't read my component.ts variables, any solution?

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm having some trouble on printing my data from the component.ts in the component.html

Here is the component.ts:

```
export class ApiComponent {

  api: Api;

  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public fourP: FourPService) {

    fourP.getAPI$.subscribe( data => {
      this.api = data;
      console.log(data.id);
      console.log(this.api.id);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
  

}
```

And here my component.html:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb m-5">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" href='#'><a href="#">4P</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" [routerLink]="'/apis'"><a href="#">API's</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">{{ api.id }}</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
```

Here you can see the response of the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9zpz.png)

Also here you can see the structure of the Api interface I created:

```
export interface Api{
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  scopes: Array<Scopes>;
  contact: Array<Contact>;
  tags: any[];
}

interface Scopes{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  guards_pi: boolean;
}

interface Contact{
  name: string;
}
```

Does anyone know why mi component.html isn´t reading the component.ts variables (i've tried calling the variable also with {{ api['id' ]}} and {{ id }} but is always shooting the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your @Component selector code and also check the same behaviour in ngOnInit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Safe Navigation Operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator) so that is prevent undefined error until it gets value.

Basically what happens is template load first and that time `api` doesnt have value and it throws undefined error.

If we use safe navigator operator it prevent throwing error if variable doesnt have value, and once it fully loaded and variable has value it shows the value.

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">{{ api?.id }}</li> <=== notice ? mark
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering, i've tried adding the question mark, now there is no error shown in the console, it stills prints the console.log()'s I have, but nothing in the component.html. =( I've also tried adding the get to the ngOnInit but it doesn´t receive the data if I do it this way

Comment: @MANZARBEITIA any stackblitz example could help to debug, however could you try `{{ api | json }}` in your template and see what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

The Safe Navigation Operator (`?`), as suggested by Kamran, is one solution to handle this problem. The error in the console is gone, but you will notice for a short period of time (until your `api` object is available) that there will be only the bullet point of the `<li>` rendered to the screen, without any text behind. Especially when the visual structure of your page depends on the variables in your ts file, you might want to avoid this second (or how long it takes until your objects are avaiable) when your page looks that incomplete.
Then you could try the following:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol *ngIf="api" class="breadcrumb m-5">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" href='#'><a href="#">4P</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" [routerLink]="'/apis'"><a href="#">API's</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">{{ api.id }}</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

With this the complete `<ol>` structure is only rendered when the `api` object has a value. No error will be thrown for the `api.id` line, because it is insinde `<ol>` and thus also only rendered when `api` has a value.

Edit:
And add a null check in the subscribe section.

```
fourP.getAPI$.subscribe( data => {
  if(data) {
     console.log('received data object has a value');
     this.api = data;
     console.log(data.id);
     console.log(this.api.id);
     console.log(data);
  } else {
     console.log('received data object is null');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried adding the ngIf you suggested, now the <ol> tag doesn´t appear in the html (so we can deduct the variable is empty), but it still prints in console the this.api.id value, so then do I have my variable empty or not? It's driving me crazy! Thanks for answering

Comment: You're saying it prints *this*.api.id. You are not using the *this* keyword in the template, but only in your .ts file (line console.log(this.api.id)). Maybe the subscribe event is raised once with a null value for data, before it is raised a second time with a value for data? You can include a null check at that point as well. I'll edit my answer.